# One to One relationship modeling

Tags: database, ms-access

I am using access 2010 to do this.

I have created two tables and I would like to get it one to one and i don't seem to get it in to one to one relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
ID VARCHAR(1) UNIQUE,
Name VARCHAR(30),

PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Passport(
ID VARCHAR(1) UNIQUE,
Country VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Person(ID)
);
```

From the little knowledge that I have, This should be a one to one relationship but it is a one to many. How do I get it one to one via ACCESS?

I have tried most things that I can find in books but with no success.

Please help.

Comment: How do you know it's one-to-many?  If it's truly one-to-one, then all the data should be in the same table.  Also, `id varchar(1)` gives you only 256 possible records.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Ok so it does not display as a one to one in the relationship but it is in actual fact a one to one but it displays a one to many.

Comment: What you have is `one to zero or one` which is as close as you will get in most relational database products without consolidating to a single table.

Comment: Btw, having a unique constraint on the primary key column is redundant; primary keys are already required to be unique.

Comment: It's entirely possible for a person to have more than one passport and for them to have a history of passports (such as when they are renewed), so you may need a one to many relationship. You just need to know which are currently valid.

Comment: How would this model deal with my 2 current passports (New Zealand and UK) plus a couple of expired ones for each?

Comment: I know your are working with Access but there's an interesting article by [Tony Rogerson](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2010/01/23/how-to-create-a-one-to-one-relationship-in-sql-server-using-dri-triggers-and-views.aspx) on creating a one-to-one relationship, for all the hassle be happy with a zero-to-one relationship :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply be misled by the way relationships are displayed in the Relationships window. I ran your exact DDL and when I view the relationship in the Relationships window it *looks* like one-to-many...

[image: gui.png]

...but when I right-click on the line joining the two tables and choose "Edit Relationship..." the dialog shows that it is actually one-to-one:

[image: details.png]

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that in fact you created a one-to-one relationship as you wish.

1. the person id is unique
2. the passport id is unique
3. the passport id(unique) equals one person id(also unique).
4. So its one-to-one

However, it should be better design to have different ids for person and passport to have more clear design. Something like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE Person(
    PERSONID VARCHAR(1) UNIQUE,
    Name VARCHAR(30),

    PRIMARY KEY (PERSONID)
   );

   CREATE TABLE Passport(
   PASSPORTID VARCHAR(1) UNIQUE,
   Country VARCHAR(30),
   PERSONID VARCHAR(1),
   PRIMARY KEY (PASSPORTID),
   FOREIGN KEY (PERSONID) REFERENCES Person(PERSONID)
   );
```

This will also accomodate cases of persons with multiple passports.